# Next image config not working for graphcms image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to just use graphcms for my image assets and load them into my Next JS (v12.0.1) frontend. However, it is just throwing this `hostname not configured in next.config.js` error even though I have already specified it in my next.config.js file as follows.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['media.graphcms.com','media.graphassets.com'],
  }
};
```

I am loading it into a component with this query using `@apollo/client` :

```
import Page from '@components/page';
import TeamMembersGrid from '@components/team-members-grid';
import Layout from '@components/layout';
import Header from '@components/header';

import { META_DESCRIPTION } from '@lib/constants';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const TEAM_MEMBERS = gql`
query TeamMember {
  teamMembers {
    phoneNumber
    name
    id
    emailAddress
    subsystem
    role
    experienceLevel
    profileImage {
      url
    }
  }
}
`;

const TeamMembers = () => {
  const { data } =useQuery(TEAM_MEMBERS);
  const team = data?.teamMembers
  const meta = {
    title: 'Raftar Formula Racing',
    description: META_DESCRIPTION
  };

  return (
    <Page meta={meta}>
      <Layout>
        <Header hero="The Crew" description={meta.description} />
        {team && <TeamMembersGrid teamMembers={team}/>}
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
}

export default TeamMembers
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly is failing here ?
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, upgrading nextjs simply to 12.1.14 worked a charm & no my project is working great !

Comment: "^12.1.4" not "^12.1.14"